# toogle class of list of elements sequentially infinitely

Tags: jquery, sequence, infinite-loop

I have a series of `div` elements that I want to show and hide sequentially using `toggleClass`. My code works like a charm.

I would now like to go back to the first div when the last div is active, and so on infinitely. I can't figure out how to do this.

```js
var timeout = 2000
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".text-sequence .text").each(function(i, el) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.toggleClass('active')
      $(".text-sequence .text").not($this).removeClass('active')
    }, i * timeout)
  })
}, timeout)
```

```css
.text {
  opacity: 0
}

.text.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-sequence">
  <div class="text">Text 1</div>
  <div class="text">Text 2</div>
  <div class="text">Text 3</div>
  <div class="text">Text 4</div>
  <div class="text">Text 5</div>
  <div class="text">Text 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit more complex than necessary. You don't need to wrap an interval in a timeout, and you don't need the loop within that timeout.

To do what you require simply target the current `.active` element and use `next()` to get the next element. You can determine if there is no next element and then go back to the `first()` again.

Note in the following example that I shortened the interval to make the effect more obvious.

```js
let timeout = 500;
let $text = $('.text-sequence .text');
let updateActiveText = () => {
  let $current = $text.filter('.active').removeClass('active');
  let $next = $current.next();
  if ($next.length == 0)
    $next = $text.first();    
  $next.addClass('active');
}

updateActiveText(); // on load
setInterval(updateActiveText, timeout) // every n iterval;
```

```css
.text {
  opacity: 0
}

.text.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-sequence">
  <div class="text">Text 1</div>
  <div class="text">Text 2</div>
  <div class="text">Text 3</div>
  <div class="text">Text 4</div>
  <div class="text">Text 5</div>
  <div class="text">Text 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following `setInterval()` example.

```js
$(function() {
  var timeout = 2000
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(index);
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(".text-sequence .text").eq(index++).addClass("active");
    if (index >= $(".text-sequence .text").length) {
      index = 0;
    }
  }, timeout);
});
```

```css
.text {
  opacity: 0
}

.text.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-sequence">
  <div class="text">Text 1</div>
  <div class="text">Text 2</div>
  <div class="text">Text 3</div>
  <div class="text">Text 4</div>
  <div class="text">Text 5</div>
  <div class="text">Text 6</div>
</div>
```

This will keep running over and over.

> The `setInterval()` method, offered on the `Window` and `Worker` interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

This also give you the option to `clearInterval()` if needed.

You could also do this in a few other ways.

```js
$(function() {
  var timeout = 2000
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(index);
    $(".active").removeClass("active").animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
    $(".text-sequence .text").eq(index++).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000).addClass("active");
    if (index >= $(".text-sequence .text").length) {
      index = 0;
    }
  }, timeout);
});
```

```css
.text {
  opacity: 0
}

.text.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-sequence">
  <div class="text">Text 1</div>
  <div class="text">Text 2</div>
  <div class="text">Text 3</div>
  <div class="text">Text 4</div>
  <div class="text">Text 5</div>
  <div class="text">Text 6</div>
</div>
```